# I get this error code Instance of 'API' has no 'me' member, i have the keys normally inserted

Tags: python, tweepy

```
import tweepy
import time

cosnsuemr_key = ''
cosnsuemr_secret = ''

    access_token = ''
    access_token_secret = ''


    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(cosnsuemr_key,cosnsuemr_secret )
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

    user = api.me()
```

Comment: When you write `api.me()`, what do you expect that to mean? Why? Why should it do anything at all? What does the documentation say about this?

Comment: It should make a connection to my twittter uses, so i van use it to for exampel print my followers as i understand

Answer (score 0):

The new [Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) removed API.me(). You can use API.verify_credentials() instead.

```
user = api.verify_credentials() 
print(user.screen_name)
```